# Multi-functional math calculator in C

Tags: c

I need write code to create a simple calculator using C language.
I need to put some basic function in here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    int a,b,sum;

    printf("");

    scanf("%d",&a);

    printf("");

    scanf("%d",&b);


    printf("enter 1 to add,2 to sub,3 to divi,4 to mul");

    scanf("%d",&sum);


    int add = a+b, sub =a-b,divi=a/b,mul=a*b;


    if(sum==1)
     printf("add of two  values= %d",add);

    if(sum==2)
     printf("sub of two values=%d",sub);

    if(sum==3)
     printf("divi of two values=%d",divi);

    if(sum==4)
     printf("mul of two values=%d",mul);

}
```

This code terminates when I input two integers and give the option. I need write the code to terminate the code when I give "=".

Comment: The problem is quite common when starting to learn C/C++..

the reason is that console applications once finisher return from their main method, the associated console window automatically closes. This behavior has nothing to do with what your app does or not, or if the app is working well or not.

To "correct" this simple add a pause just before the return statement in the main method

Example:

....
   system("pause");  
   return 0;
}

Comment: Did you forget to wrap it in a loop?

Comment: loop thanks dude.can you show me to how to write.

Comment: Please all of use let @Code_thinks_2_code to edit it. Code_thinks_2_code please use the tools to format the code. If you have problems read the help

Comment: Also I assume you are using C - so dump the C++ tag

Comment: So, them go ahead and write the code.  You haven't actually asked a question here.

Comment: If you want to support '(' and ')' operators for sure you will need some regex.

Comment: in that code terminate in two integer ok but i need to stop that terminate

Comment: @Code_thinks_2_code I suggest you read a good C tutorial once again.

Comment: yeah i'm a newbie to the c

Comment: It is `int main` in C, not `void main`.

Comment: Relevant? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345555/1566221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you didn't put a pause at the end of the main().

To fix it you can either put at the end of main command system("pause"); or you could do it this way

```
 char c; std::cin >> c;
 return;
```

This way it will wait for character input and then if you want to terminate your application when you input '=' 
you can write :

```
 if (c=='=') return;
```

Simple :)

If you want your calculator to do multiple calculations until you insert that '=' sign. You can do it this way :

```
 int main()
{

char c;



while(c!='N'){

//YOUR CODE GOES HERE AND IT WILL BE REPEATED UNTIL YOU INSERT N at the end



std::cout << "\n Do one more calculation ? (Y/N) : ";
std::cin >> c;
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

**C:**

```
    while(c!='N'){

    //YOUR CODE GOES HERE AND IT WILL BE REPEATED UNTIL YOU INSERT N at the end



//Doing it this way, if you type N it will terminate, if you type any other character it will do the loop.
printf(" Do one more calculation ? (Y/N) : ");
scanf("%c", &c);
}
```

Comment: Really?  A C++ solution for a C question?

Comment: @Code_thinks_2_code If you can't work it through, I'll do it in C

Comment: @Peter The question was initially tagged with C++

Comment: @Peter - To be fair it was initially tagged C and C++ when this was the answer

Comment: It's hard to know what to do with a question that says "in C" in the title and then dual tags the question with C and C++, and shows code that is more C than C++.